# gocd - making custom command script available to agent

Tags: go-cd

I am trying to add a custom command which in turn calls a python script, as per example here https://support.thoughtworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/213253646-Go-s-custom-command,

```
<exec command="myecho.sh">
</exec>
```

In my case,

```
<exec command="/usr/bin/python cd_dashboard.py">
  <arg>-v</arg>
</exec>
```

But when I execute the pipeline it fails with following error,

[go] Task: "/usr/bin/python cd_dashboard.py" -vtook: 0.2s
Error happened while attempting to execute '/usr/bin/python cd_dashboard.py -v'. 
Please make sure [/usr/bin/python cd_dashboard.py] can be executed on this agent.

So the question is where should the python script reside to be accessible to agent? Should be in agent's PATH.

Is this correct understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be **/usr/bin/python**, please move **cd_dashboard.py** to the args. Right now GoCD trying to run executable `/usr/bin/python cd_dashboard.py`, which of course doesn't exist. You should have something like this:

```
<exec command="/usr/bin/python">
  <arg>-v</arg>
  <arg>cd_dashboard.py</arg>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks.Where should cd_dashboard.py reside. Can it reside in the custom_command default repo and still be accessible to agent or needs to be explicitly made available on agent?

Comment: Yes, it can be part of default repository, in this case GoCD will automatically clone/download it on each agent, where this job will be executed.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.